# Unable to decode yml file ... utf8' codec can't decode byte #xa0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pyyaml

I'm trying to read YAML file and convert it into dictionary file. I'm seeing an issue while loading the file into dict variable.

I tried to search for similar issues. One of the replies in stackoverflow was to replace each character `'\\xa0'` with `' '`. I tried do that `line = line.replace('\\xa0',' ')`. This program doesn't work on Python 2.7 version. I tried using Python 3 it works fine.

```
import yaml
import sys

yaml_dir = "/root/tools/test_case/"

#file_name = "TC_CFD_SR.yml"
file_name = "TC_QB.yml"
tc_file_name = yaml_dir + file_name

def write(file,content):
    file = open(file,'a')
    file.write(content)
    file.close()

def verifyYmlFile(yml_file):
    data = {}
    with open(yml_file, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.replace('\\xa0',' ')
            write('anand-yaml.yml',line)

    with open('anand-yaml.yml','r') as fin:
        data = yaml.load(fin)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {}
    print "verifying yaml"
    data= verifyYmlFile(tc_file_name)
```

Error:

```
[root@anand-harness test_case]# python verify_yaml.py 
verifying yaml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "verify_yaml.py", line 29, in <module>
    data= verifyYmlFile(tc_file_name)
  File "verify_yaml.py", line 23, in verifyYmlFile
    data = yaml.load(fin)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 71, in load
    return loader.get_single_data()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 37, in get_single_data
    node = self.get_single_node()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 36, in get_single_node
    document = self.compose_document()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 55, in compose_document
    node = self.compose_node(None, None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 82, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_sequence_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 111, in compose_sequence_node
    node.value.append(self.compose_node(node, index))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 84, in compose_node
    node = self.compose_mapping_node(anchor)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 133, in compose_mapping_node
    item_value = self.compose_node(node, item_key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/composer.py", line 64, in compose_node
    if self.check_event(AliasEvent):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 98, in check_event
    self.current_event = self.state()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/parser.py", line 449, in parse_block_mapping_value
    if not self.check_token(KeyToken, ValueToken, BlockEndToken):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 116, in check_token
    self.fetch_more_tokens()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 244, in fetch_more_tokens
    return self.fetch_single()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 653, in fetch_single
    self.fetch_flow_scalar(style='\'')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 667, in fetch_flow_scalar
    self.tokens.append(self.scan_flow_scalar(style))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 1156, in scan_flow_scalar
    chunks.extend(self.scan_flow_scalar_non_spaces(double, start_mark))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/scanner.py", line 1196, in scan_flow_scalar_non_spaces
    while self.peek(length) not in u'\'\"\\\0 \t\r\n\x85\u2028\u2029':
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 91, in peek
    self.update(index+1)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/yaml/reader.py", line 165, in update
    exc.encoding, exc.reason)
yaml.reader.ReaderError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte #xa0: invalid start byte
  in "anand-yaml.yml", position 3246
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, @user. As you may know, Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site. Users, such as yourself, ask programming questions and other users try to answer them. I see that your post includes a code fragment and a full error message. Thanks!  What I don't see is a question. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: Why not open the file using the proper encoding?

Comment: Your backtrace looks like it was made with Python 2.6. Anyhow, if it works in Python 3, what is your problem? That said, do you know what `'\\xa0'` should be? And do you understand the workaround and what it should do?

Comment: Hey, I know that program works in python3 ... i was wondering why it is not working for python2.6. Let me try to open the file using proper encoding. Moreover I need to make this program run in python2.6 environment.

Answer (score 0):

The character sequence "`\\xa0`" is not the problem that you see in the message, the problem is the sequence "`\xa0`" (note that the backslash is not escaped).
You replacement line should be:

```
     line = line.replace('\xa0',' ')
```

to circumvent the problem.

If you know what the format is you can do the correct conversion yourself, but that should not be necessary and that or the above patching is not a structural solution. It would be  best if the YAML file was generated in a correct way (they default to UTF-8, so it should contain correct UTF-8). It could UTF-16 without the appropriate BOM (which the yaml library interprets IIRC).

```
s1 = 'abc\\xa0xyz'
print(repr(s1))
u1 = s1.decode('utf-8') # this works fine

s = 'abc\xa0xyz'
print(repr(s))
u = s.decode('utf-8') # this throws an error
```